# how to avoid .html extension being appended when downloading or opening my file

Tags: cakephp

When I am saving a file in a img/upload folder the file is saved with the correct file-extension.

However, when I try to *download* the file, a .htm file-extension is appended.

How can I avoid this? I've added my code below;

view.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->label("Resume:");?> 
      <?php echo $this->Form->input("resume",array("class"=>"input_boxstyle_select","label"=>"","type"=>"file","id"=>"file"));?> 
      <a href="../download_resume/<?php echo $editEmpPros[0]['prospective_employee']['resume']?>" style="margin-left:140px;color:#0477CA;"> <?php echo $editEmpPros[0]['prospective_employee']['resume']?> </a>
```

Inside my controller:

```
public function download_resume($id=null)
{
    $LUser = $this->Session->read('username');  
    $this->disableCache(); 
    if (!$LUser) {
        $this->redirect(array("action"=>"../"));                 
    }

    $path="../webroot/img/upload/$id";
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment'); readfile($path);
    //print_r(readfile($path));
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Handling file-downloads in CakePHP 2.x

While other solutions may work, CakePHP handles the response via the [`CakeResponse` object](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse). This chapter in the manual describes how to send (download) files; [**Sending Files**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files)

The response will automatically attempt to set the right mime-type, based on the file-extension

#### To *output* the file (inside the browser);

```
$this->response->file(WEBROOT_DIR . '/img/upload/' . $filename);

//Return reponse object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
return $this->response;
```

#### To *download* the file (and, optionally, specify a custom filename)

To force *downloading* the file and specify a custom filename (if desired), use this code. CakeResponse object will automatically set the right headers, so manually specifying a custom filename should *not* be necessary

```
// To force *downloading* the file and specify a custom filename (if desired)
$this->response->file(
    WEBROOT_DIR . '/img/upload/' . $filename,
    array(
        'download' => true,
        'name'     => 'custom-filename-for-downloading'
    )
);
return $this->response;
```

Comment: I am bumping into an issue where I am using this syntax, but the name parameter does not work correctly. The file has the correct name on the server, but the file that is downloaded is named for the Cakephp action that does the download. Has this ever happened to you before?

Answer (score 2):

You can give the filename in the Content-Disposition header too, like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.bar"
```

Comment: Correct answer. Depending on the version of CakePHP, OP should use the 'CakeResponse' object in order to send files. I added an answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browsers you have to support you could also use the `download` attribute of HTML5:

```
<a href="/path-to-your-file" download="your-desired-filename">my link</a>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion! A bit premature regarding browser support, but the future looks bright!

Answer (score 0):

you have to set some parameter as here i am giving you one example to download PDF file

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Please make parameter as you need..

let me know if i can help you more.